# Does Apache Cordova need a server?

Tags: apache, cordova, server

I see that it uses HTML, CSS, and JS, but does that package with the app or does it need a server if it is a static page?

Also if a server is needed could i get away with hosting on Github pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML, CSS, and JS files are bundled with the app bundle and loaded from local storage. This means that your content comes from `file://` (unless you have certain plugins installed that create an http server on localhost).

You'll only need a server if you need one as a backend (which you'd communicate with via XHR/Ajax).